# How can I change the video Poster using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am doing a video list work. In that, there are three links with three different ids. Once the user click on the link, the video and the poster of the video has to change. While I am using my jquery code, the video is changing but the attr "poster" is not change at all ... any reason? This is my code what I am using...

video HTML code :

```
<video width="600" height="360" id="player2" poster="videos/video1/video1.jpg" controls="controls" preload="none">
    <!-- MP4 source must come first for iOS -->
    <source type="video/mp4" src="videos/video1/video1.mp4" />
    <!-- WebM for Firefox 4 and Opera -->
    <source type="video/webm" src="videos/video1/video1.webm" />
    <!-- OGG for Firefox 3 -->
    <source type="video/ogg" src="videos/video1/video1.ogv" />
    <!-- Fallback flash player for no-HTML5 browsers with JavaScript turned off -->
    <object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="videos/flashmediaelement.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="videos/flashmediaelement.swf" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;file=videos/video1/video1.mp4" />
        <!-- Image fall back for non-HTML5 browser with JavaScript turned off and no Flash player installed -->
        <img src="videos/video1/video1.jpg" width="640" height="360" alt="Here we are"
            title="No video playback capabilities" />
    </object>
</video>
```

My jquery code:

```
$('div.video-box-area img').click(function(){
    var nowSrc = $('video').attr('src');
    var change = nowSrc.replace(nowSrc.substr(12,1),$(this).parent().attr('id').substr(length-1));

    var poster = $('video').attr("poster");
    var posterChange = poster.replace(poster.substr(12,1),$(this).parent().attr('id').substr(length-1));

    $('video').attr("poster",posterChange);
    $('video').attr('src',change);

    return false;
});
```

Comment: BTW, while its not the answer you are looking for, I would group all your attribute reads before the calculation including the $(this).parent().attr('id') which is inline in your two calculations. Right now both calculations will require jQuery to walk up the DOM which will slow it down. Read the ID once, then use it as needed. Also because you didn't supply the complete markup it is impossible for us to help debug this. We are only guessing what $(this).parent().attr('id') looks like. This makes it hard to debug your replace-substring statements.

Answer (score 2):

According to [HTML5 video specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#attr-video-poster), **the poster is displayed** when **no video data is available** (the video's readyState attribute is either HAVE_NOTHING, or HAVE_METADATA but no video data has yet been obtained at all, or the element's readyState attribute is any subsequent value but the media resource does not have a video channel). When video is paused, and the current playback position is the first frame of video, the element represents either the frame of video corresponding to the current playback position or the poster frame, depend on browsers.

In your circumstance, the video data is probably available, so the poster is not rendered. I can help you investigate the problem if you give me a live demo.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can access the attribute directly by using the tagname.

What I am referrering to is your `$('video')` tag, by my experience that should return an array of all the  tags on the page, if you can, you should match it by **id** instead.

If that is not a possibility, and you are absolutely sure there's only one video tag on the page, you can do something like `$('video')[0]` but that is not a good solution.

Can you post your entire code, including the `<div class="video-box-area">`?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried a [few things](http://jsfiddle.net/Dxt54/1/) and it looks like your jquery calls are okay. The only thing i can see is if the `posterChange` variable is actually `posterValue == ''`. If the string is empty, the attr won't be changed.

Do an alert right after you calculate the posterChange variable and see if it is empty...

Comment: Poster url's are changing. but nothing is updating that's the issue..!

Comment: please put up the whole code. I've [tried][1] running your example piece above (should be able to run standalone) but it always crashing at `...var change = nowSrc.replace...`. 

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/FNxZA/2/